# adding relays to power headlights in a ford transit custom van

Tags: led

first off i am a beginner/diy chap soley trying to improve my personal vehicle and i am  in no way in my comfort zone here with electronics i am extremely basic a friend gave me advice on the relay set up over the phone and all i did was carry out from the guidance. Allow me to provide what i have done thus far may be far from adequate for you guys to help me but i am hoping we can muddle threw, Allow me to start with the basic plan

I have a 2014 ford transit custom with standard H7 headlight bulbs

I have replaced the front panels on my van with the new shape panels to give the van a modern look,  2018 2019 design in turn i have replaced the both front headlights.

My original headlights have DRL lamps standard bulbs,  my new headlights have led drls.

I fitted the new shape headlights,  and the led drls worked,  my main beam did not nor do the drls dim when the main bean is turned on (they should dim 50%) nor do them dim when we indicate again should dim 50%.

So i tackled the lack of low and high beam first and this is how i go them to work

i used a 4 pin 12v 20amp relay,  i took ground from the body to pin 2, then 12v with a inline 10amp fuse to pin 3 relay,  the headlight plug i cut pin 8 and took that wire to pin 3 on my relay and returned the harness side on pin 5.

I did this on both headlights so they both have a relay each,  and my main bean and dipped work.

I have two sets of headlights for the facelift model,  one is fitted with standard h7 bulbs the other set are factory hid bi xenon lights, both sets now work.

the only issue i had was i would get a error msg on my dash complaining the dipped headlights are not working,  i have two fault codes for low beam circuit both left and right = the 2 fault codes. B1D00 and B1D01

i used croc clips temporary for testing connected a h7 bulb to pin 1 and 2 on the relay,  both sides and the error codes were gone,  so i have tried numerous resistors 50w 4.7ohms 5-6 ohms and nothing worked again i put them across pin 1 and 2 relay,  the h7 bulbs when connected across pin 1 and 2 were given me 120ohms the draw 2.78amps per bulb

question 1 is are my calcs way off with using 4,7ohms in a resistor (i am going off what's available online with titles for h7 canbus errors)

question 2 is i cant figure out to be honest why the van is fitted with h7 from factory but will not work with the new headlights again with h7,  if anything i expected them to work (h7) and the bi xenon to require relays only thing i can think is the leds draw more power and that was taking the power away from the main beam?

the next issue i had was i had no sidelights,  i had at this point

high beam
low beam
corner lights
drls
indicators

but no sidelight,  so i bridged harness side pins 2 and 3 together (the drls are used as the sidelights normally on the new shape model anyway)  and that gave me sidelights.

i plan to resolve the dim with a drl auto dim kit i have bought on amazon,  that i intend to look at at some point once i figure out the original question 1

i am sure my design has many floors and i wanted to run it by you guys here and see what you made of my attempts.

there is an additional issue that has raised its head today which i wont go into detail just yet as i would like to discuss my first stages at this point in time.

i have uploaded the original ford wiring harness (plug to headlamp) for my van and the facelift new shape wiring harness diagrams they are quite similar left is my original wiring the right is a new shape wiring .[image: left image is my vans original the right is the new shape vans wiring]

Comment: You may get a better response if you ask this in the Motor Vehicle Maintenance section.

Comment: you'll find it at https://Mechanics.stackexchange.com4